# Disable all past dates except for the last 2 days from jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I am trying to disable all past dates from the date-picker except for the last 2 dates.  How can i do that?

```
<link href="Content/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();
        });
</script>
```

here is my textbox

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" >asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `minDate` option for this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -2});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: -2
});
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/368/)**